Pass class function as function parameter JS
I have defined following function:
function handleMessageDot(fun) {
    domElement.classList.fun('hidden');
}

Now I want to use one of those:
handleMessageDot(add), handleMessageDot(remove).
I get remove is not defined error. I assume that is because remove() and add() functions are classList methods.
I now I can do the following:
function handleMessageDot(domElement, fun) {
    domElement.classList.fun('hidden');
}

but I don't want to do that.
Is there a way to do 'my' way?

When attempting to access the property of an object using the value of a separate variable you need to use array notation:


const handleMessageDot = (domElement, fun) => domElement.classList[fun]('hidden');

handleMessageDot(document.querySelector('.hidden'), 'remove');
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<div class="hidden">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>




That did a job. Thanks!
